# What is the best substitute for sherry vinegar?

Tags: substitutions, soup, vinegar

I want to make an Ajo Blanco soup and one of the ingredients is sherry vinegar, but where I live I didn't find it to buy it. The recipe calls for 2 tbsp. I have never tasted sherry vinegar, so I have no idea how I can replace it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Other than balsamic vinegar and Chingkiang vinegar, all vinegars are reasonably substitutable for each other. White wine vinegar in particular will substitute well for sherry vinegar. (So will malt vinegar or cider vinegar or whatever you have lying around.)

Answer (score 5):

I would go with red wine vinegar, and then white wine vinegar in that order.

I am not sure whether red wine vinegar is readily available everywhere though.

Comment: add apple cider vinegar.

Comment: This seems counterintuitive given that sherry is derived from white wine. Can you elaborate on why you'd prefer a red wine vinegar?

Comment: I don't have a scientific explanation for it, all I can say is that's what we do at home, and my home is in a Mediterranean country, and my mum did the same before me and her mum before her.